# Trouble configuring ActionMailer default_url_options from Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I was getting the following error when sending a mail (though mail worked correctly previously):

```
"Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host] (ActionView::Template::Error)"
```

I was sure that I has set my action mailer config correctly and, on inspection, I was right. However, it seems that Rails randomly stopped picking up this configuration.

When I tried accessing the `default_url_options` on a view to check they're being set, it would show an empty hash.

My only solution was to replace this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}
```

with this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options  = {:host => "localhost:3000"}
```

Which I would interpret as the same thing. This worked fine but I'm still confused over what went wrong here. My Gemfile didn't change or anything like that - a bit of a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I wrote in the different environments files:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```